# "Cannot assign requested address" when binding to INADDR_LOOPBACK, but INADDR_ANY works

Tags: c, linux, tcp

*Note: I found the solution which researching for this question. The next one making this mistake will hopefully discover this question before spending to much time on this.*

I've been trying to implement a TCP server on a Linux system. The problem is that I receive a very generic error message that doesn't reveal the cause of the problem:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c
$ ./a.out
bind: Cannot assign requested address
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main() {
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = 8080;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_LOOPBACK;

    if(bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bind: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(close(sockfd) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "close: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

There are countless questions on this site that describe a similar problem, but the key thing here is that it works when I try to bind to `INADDR_ANY` instead of `INADDR_LOOPBACK`. I found a few questions that had this issue, but the other way around which is a bit weird.

*What are possible causes for this error message?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been assigning the port and address wrong:

```c
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = 8080;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_LOOPBACK;
```

should be

```c
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
```

`htons` stands for "host to network short" and `htonl` stands for "host to network long", and are refering to the byte order in which the address and port are encoded.

`INADDR_ANY` is the address `0.0.0.0`, the byte order doesn't matter here. `INADDR_LOOPBACK` is the address `127.0.0.1` which was incorrectly understood as `1.0.0.127`.